# Railsのルーティングでresourceベースでない場合の書き方について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby2.2.0 Rails4.2.0 をつかっています。
Railsのルーティングでresourceベースでない場合の書き方について
いろいろ書き方はあると思いますが、どの書き方が良いのかわかりません。。
2.のような、=> を使った方がモダンでスマートな書き方だよと教えてもらったのですが
すべて統一して => を使って書くのが良いとされているのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問ですみません。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
1. get 'hello1', to: 'pages#hello'
2. get 'hello2', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'hello2'
3. get 'hello3/:id', to: 'pages#hello3'
4. post 'hello4', to: 'pages#hello4'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APIリファレンス](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html)でもデフォルトで生成される`config/routes.rb`でも

```
 get 'post/:id' => 'posts#show'
 get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

などとなっているので、まずはこれに倣うのがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

[rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)を読む限りでは

```
get 'hello2', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'hello2'
```

この書き方を特に推奨している感じはありません。何がスマートでモダンなのか根拠がわからないので何とも言えないのですが、どれを使っても実質は変わらないので、極論すれば好みの問題ではないかとも思います。
また、質問の趣旨とは違うかもしれませんが、書き方を統一したほうが良いかどうかという点については、単なる書き方のスタイルという面とは観点がやや異なる部分があります。というのも意図もなく一個一個ばらばらの書き方をしてはコードの可読性を下げるからで、むしろそちらを重視して「書き方を統一しよう」という話になることが私の経験上では多いです。